# Role of higher fermion generations in ordinary matter

Tags: particle-physics, fermions, elementary-particles

Do the second and third generation fermions play any significant role in ordinary, everyday matter or physical processes? Could a hypothetical alternate universe without higher generation fermions (perhaps with a few tweaks to the parameters of the laws of physics) look basically the same as ours at the macroscopic level?